# Oracle: making column name dynamic

Tags: oracle

I have a table with the months pivoted like this:

```
product rev_jan unit_jan prod_jan rev_feb  rev_march u...
```

I need to get the data for the current month.

Currently I am using bind variable.

```
select 
rev_&1,
prod_&1,
unit_&1
from 
table_name
```

Is there a better way solution as in this method I have to prompt the month 3 times.

Answer (score 2):

What the OP describes is supplying arguments to a sqlplus script on the sqlplus "command line".  If the file contains the following contents:

```
select 
rev_&1,
prod_&1,
unit_&1
from 
table_name;
```

then sqlplus will take the first "command line argument" from the prompt, e.g.

```
SQL> @script.sql arg1
```

and substitute '&1' with the literal value arg1 without prompting three times (or however many times the substring '&1' appears in the script).

If you don't supply an argument on the "command line", then sqlplus will prompt for the value of "&1" every time it appears in the script (here, 3 times).

To avoid having the '&' character interpreted by sqlplus, you can use sqlplus's "set define off" or concatenate a single '&' character literal in your strings: `'AT' || '&' || 'T'`.

Alternatively, you can set up prompts in your script for readability:

```
accept a_month prompt 'Please enter the desired month: '
select 
    rev_&a_month,
    prod_&a_month,
    unit_&a_month
    from 
    table_name;
```

Then, invoke the script from the sqlplus prompt as follows:

```
SQL> @script.sql
Please enter the desired month: jan
```

(Script executes here.)

For a sqlplus reference, please see the [Oracle manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIIEDF).